# looping through an array with a button in titanium

Tags: titanium

I am a student so I apologize for asking such a simple question. I am trying to make a "next and "previous" button that loops through an array one at a time.

```
var food = ["pasta", "Salad", "Apple", "Pizza"];
    counter=0;

    var displayAlert = function(){ 
        for (var i=0, item; i<food.length; i++) {
        item = food[i];
        quoteText.text=food[i];
}   
};      

    var quoteView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    height: 150,
    top: 50,
    left: 20,
    right: 20,
    borderRadius: 5

});


var quoteText = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: "click below to begin",
    font: {fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "Arial"},
    textAlign: "center"
});
    quoteView.add(quoteText);
    mainWindow.add(quoteView);



buttonPrevious.addEventListener("click", displayAlert);
buttonNext.addEventListener("click", displayAlert);
```

Comment: No need to apologize. What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to output the whole array on every button click? Do you want to output the next/previous item of the array on button click?

Answer (score 0):

So I have worked through the code with my instructor and although I will take a zero on this assignment, someone else might benefit from my misfortune.

```
var food = ["pasta", "Salad", "Apple", "Pizza"];
    counter=0;

    var displayAlert = function(){
        console.log (counter);
    quoteText.text=food[counter];
    if (counter === food.length-1){
        counter=0;  
    }
    else {counter=counter+1};
};      
    var getPrevious = function(){
        quoteText.text=food[counter];
    if (counter === 0){
        counter=food.length-1;
    }
    else {counter=counter-1};

};
    var quoteView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    height: 150,
    top: 50,
    left: 20,
    right: 20,
    borderRadius: 5

});


var quoteText = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: "click below to begin",
    font: {fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "Arial"},
    textAlign: "center"
});
    quoteView.add(quoteText);
    mainWindow.add(quoteView);
```